# expectation of upper quantile proportion

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, expectation

(**edited considerably following comments**)

We have a collection $\boldsymbol{S}$ of $n$ discrete random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $\dots$, $X_n$ $\overset{\small \text{i.i.d.}}{\small \sim}$ $\mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is a distribution over $\{1, 2, \ldots, U\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ with cumulative distribution function $F_\mathcal{D}$.

We define the subcollection that includes only the values in $\boldsymbol{S}$ that are above $Q(p)$, where $Q$ is the quantile function. That is:

$$
\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p} \overset{\small \text{def}}{=} \left\{X : X \in \boldsymbol{S} \text{ and } p\leq F_{\mathcal{D}}(X)\right\}
$$

(in words: $X \in \boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}$ if and only if it $p$ proportion of the population are smaller or equal to it)

(below we mark $\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{C}$ as the sum of all elements in collection $\boldsymbol{C}$)

We're interested in the quantity $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}}{\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}}\right]$ (nicknamed "*upper quantile proportion*") and wish to check if the following inequality holds for some constant $A$:

$$
\tag{1}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}}{\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}} \right]\overset{\small \text{?}}{\leq} A
$$

In practice, we're looking for an appropriate $n$ for a given parameters $0 \leq \delta \leq 1$, $\frac{1}{2} < p < 1$. For which the following is correct if $(1)$ is true:

$$
P\left[\frac{\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}}{\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}} \geq A\right] < \delta\:\:?
$$

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? thank you!

**Note 1 (my first steps)**:

Considering that membership in $\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}$ can be viewed as a simple Bernoulli random variable with probability $1 - p$, we can get the following bound using Hoeffding's inequality with parameter $\varepsilon > 0$:

$$
\Pr \Big(| \boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}| \geq (1 - p + \varepsilon)n\Big) \leq \mathrm{e}^{-2 \varepsilon^2 n}
$$

Therefore for any $\delta > 0$ and $n \geq \ln{\frac{1}{\delta}} / 2\varepsilon^2$,  we can bound $\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}$  with $1-\delta$ confidence:

$$\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p} \leq \pmb{\sum}\{x : x \in \boldsymbol{S} \land x \geq  \text{$\lfloor(p - \varepsilon)n\rfloor$-th element in $\boldsymbol{S}$}\}    
$$

Additionally, it is easy to produce a lower bound on $\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}$, so in essence we can check:

$$
\frac{\mathbb{E} \pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}}{\mathbb{E}\pmb{\sum}\boldsymbol{S}} \overset{\small \text{?}}{\leq} A
$$

but I'm not sure what this means in relation to $(1)$

**Note 2**: I also accidentally posted this in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329721/expectation-of-upper-quantile-proportion and then flagged it to be moved here by an admin.

Comment: I don’t think the quantity $X_p/X$ makes sense: it’s either 1 or undefined if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas hmm I'm not sure what you mean, it's a ratio that is usually between 0 and 1

Comment: Are $X$ and $X_{\ge p}$ defined on the same probability space? If not, are they put on the same space by making them independent?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas They are dependent. $X_{\ge p}$ is defined for a subspace of $X$ (upper quantile). This what makes the problem difficult I guess (for me#

Comment: I really don’t think your question makes sense. If I understand it right, $X_{\ge p}$ is equal to $X$ if $X$ is above the $p$th quantile; and not defined otherwise. So the ratio is 1 if $X$ is above the $p$th percentile and undefined otherwise. If this isn’t what you mean, then you need to specify the joint distribution of $X$ and $X_{\ge p}$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas you were right, thank you! I'm apologize for the inaccuracies. You already helped by pointing to the problems and I've considerably edited the question. Could you take another look? thank's again.

Comment: @MattF. thanks. I've removed the $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Ok — but now you’re not really looking at expectations. So I would delete the two expectations from the post, and change the tag from expectations to order-statistics.

Comment: @MattF I don't have enough reputation to create new tags (I would want to add 'Order-statistic' tag). In any case, I'm not sure if I should delete the expectations. $\boldsymbol{S}$ and $\boldsymbol{S}_{\geq p}$ are collections of random variables, I'm not sure if I can just compare them to a constant $A$.

Comment: I thought there was an order-statistics tag, but I guess not. I still think it would be better without the expectations.

Comment: @MattF removing the expectation would just solve my question I guess :). Bounding the numerator and denominator would be enough. Though I'm not sure if this would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

So the best possible constant is 1. Imagine that $X_j$ takes the value $U$ with probability $p$ and 1 with probability $1-p$. Clearly $\sum S_{\ge p}\le \sum S$, so that the expected ratio is at most 1. On the other hand $\sum S\le \sum S_{\ge p}+n$ (since the random variables take the value 0 and 1 only). That is: 
$$
1-\frac{n}{\sum S}\le \frac{\sum S_{\ge p}}{\sum S}\le 1.
$$
As $U$ and $n$ are taken to be large $\mathbb E(n/\sum S)$ tends to 0.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response but I'm not sure about the bound $\sum S \le \sum S_{\ge p}+n$. The random variables $X$ are in $[U]$  we can have $\sum S_{< p} > n$

Comment: That bound is because the $X$ variables take the value 1 or $U$. The biggest possible contribution from the 1’s is when all of the $X$’s are 1, giving a total of $n$.